# mysql - Use two "%" in LIKE clause

Tags: mysql

I want to use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM   blabla
WHERE      date LIKE '2014%'
       AND name = 'Jo%'
       AND (( price > 0
           OR time > 10));
```

But it doesn't return results because of

```
name = 'Jo%'
```

(but I know that there are results). I've tried 'Jo*' but it doesn't work.
It seems that only let one "%", right after LIKE clause.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `name LIKE '%Jo%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `date LIKE '2014%' AND name LIKE 'Jo%'`, because the equals sign does not perform that [pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).